# unable to create project in django 1.5.1

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I am new to Django and i am getting an error while trying to create a project.
I am using Django 1.5.1 on python 2.7
I am using the following command to create a project.

```
django-admin.py startproject mysite
```

> > SyntaxError: invalid syntax

I also added python and django in environment variables.

Comment: Can you explain what do you mean with `added python and django in environment variables`? Depending on what you did here, it may cause problems later on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are not supposed to run `django-admin.py startproject mysite` from the python console. It leads to this error.

You need to run it from the command prompt instead